# how to add double or datetime type in attribute in class diagram in modeling project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

how to add double or datetime type in attribute in class diagram in modeling project?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the class on the diagram and choose Add | Field from the context menu. Then type in Type column your type, there should be Intellisense help ready to you.

By the way, are we talking about this issue:

[image]

Comment: in visual studio 2010, properties -> type -> primitive types can not find double and datetime

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this date property to your attribute in your model and then find a tool which has the show all attribute property option in the class diagram.
I Know that RSA has this feature. The picture below is coming from EclipseUML Omondo.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ejb3.org](https://www.ejb3.org/class_diagram.png))</sub>